# Using the mutex accessed through a member pointer to regulate thread access to that class

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Though this code works, I just want to be sure that it's OK for a class to access/use the mutex accessed through a member pointer to regulate thread access to that class. I wanted to avoid using a globally accessible mutex:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    std::mutex mtx_;
public:
    Foo () : mtx_ {}, a_ {} {}
    std::mutex& get_mutex() { return mtx_; }
    void increment() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        ++a_;
    }
    void print() { std::cout << a_ << '\n'; }
    int a_;
    // std::atomic_int a_;  // not used
};

class Bar {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr;
    Bar() : ptr {} {}
    void increment() const {
        if (ptr) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(ptr->get_mutex());  // get Foo's mutex and lock it
            ++ptr->a_;
        }
    }
};

void loop1(Foo *f) {
    for (int i{}; i < 1000000; ++i) { f->increment(); }
}

void loop2(Bar *b) {
    for (int i{}; i < 1000000; ++i) { b->increment(); }
}

int main() {
    Bar b;
    Foo *f = new Foo;
    b.ptr.reset(f);

    std::thread th1(loop1, f);
    std::thread th2(loop2, &b);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    f->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you calling directly ptr->increment() but instead you manually increase a_ inside Bar:: increment?

Comment: @Liuka This isn't the actual code. In the actual code, what's in main() is inside the Bar class. I was trying to cut it down to show the principle here.

Comment: @Liuka I'm not doing this just to increment a variable..

Comment: Ok, got it. Still the same idea applies: why not calling a method on the member class instead of accessing it's variables? From a syntactic/programming point of view there is no problem in what you're doing. It's just a bit awkward and breaks encapsulation